# Fix for Sonarqube - XML parsers should not be vulnerable to XXE attacks impacts xml validation in spring boot

Tags: java, xsd, sonarqube, schema

My working code -

```
@PostMapping("/process/validate")
    public boolean validateProcessWithXSD(@Parameter(hidden = true) @RequestHeader(value = "Authorization", required = true) String jwtToken
            , int xsdVersion, @RequestBody ProcessObj processBytes) throws Exception {
        boolean isValidated;
        try {
            String xsdPath = "/assets/runtimeXsds/Process.v" + xsdVersion + ".xsd";
            InputStream xsdStream = request.getSession().getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(xsdPath);
            Source source = new StreamSource(xsdStream);
            SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI); //Sonarqube Blocker - Disable access to external entities in XML parsing.
            factory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
            javax.xml.validation.Schema schema = factory.newSchema(source);
            Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
            validator.validate(new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(processBytes.getBytes())));
            isValidated = true;
        
        return isValidated;
    }
```

Now, if I include fix -

```
factory.setProperty(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
factory.setProperty(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_SCHEMA, "");
```

Then API fails -

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 4; columnNumber: 154; schema_reference: Failed to read schema document 'xmldsig-core-schema.xsd', because 'http' access is not allowed due to restriction set by the accessExternalSchema property.
```

Changing above fix with `"http"` value works fine but then sonarqube re-appears.

Tried many ways as suggested in [XML External Entity Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/XML_External_Entity_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) and similar SO posts but issue remains.